# Only allow ssh connections to a specific domain

Tags: security, ssh

I have a server setup with several domains and subdomains.

I'd like to limit ssh and sftp access so a user can only connect to xxx.domain1.com but I'm not sure where this is configured.

Connecting via ay other domain/subdomain on the server should be refused.

Thanks,

J

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It makes no difference in the end whatsoever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since SSH doesn't know something like the `Host` header in HTTP/1.1, you cannot deny a specific user to login to your server. The SSH daemon can't know which domain originally resolved to the IP address it is listening on.

You could only get another IP address, set it as A resource record for `subdomain.example.com` and allow the user only to login on that specific IP address.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use the `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` files to limit access to `sshd`.

Add the following line to `/etc/hosts.deny`:

> `sshd: ALL`

And add the following to `/etc/hosts.allow`:

> `sshd: xxx.domain1.com`

Additionally, you can use [`denyhosts`](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) to further protect sshd from unwanted access.

Comment: Don't do this! I have lost SSH access after following this comment...

Comment: Yeah don't do this. This permits access FROM only a single domain. What the OP wanted was to restrict connections TO a single subdomain in a 'virtualhost' manner.