# Only allow a connection from specific domains

Tags: linux, networking

I bought a small VPS system earlier today to handle my website database, and went away for a couple of hours, but when I came back and logged in again, I found that an IP address in China had been attempting to login ***162*** times:

[image]

I immediately blocked the IP range using `sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 61.174.51.0/24 -j DROP`
, but I want to increase the security of my system further and only allow a connection from a specific domain.
The VPS system will only be accessed from `%.wavetelecom.com` and `%.northhosts.co.uk`, so I cannot see any issues occuring such as being locked out of the VPS.

This [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/148628/only-allow-ssh-connections-to-a-specific-domain) is similar, but I want to lock out the whole system from ***everyone*** except two domains.

Is it possible to only allow connections from a specific domain on Linux (Fedora 19)?

Comment: Nothing has changed in the intervening 165 days to change the answer you already have.

Comment: Indeed - which is in fact the correct answer, whether or not it matches what was desired.

Comment: I opened the bounty to award the user who answered the question, but am unable to award it for 16 more hours. Extra downvotes on my questions are unwarranted and will possibly be reversed when the script is run.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ You might, then, want to also accept the answer. Opening a bounty on a question where one has not accepted the answer tends to indicate dissatisfaction with the current answer(s). Your bounty message does nothing to discourage this interpretation.

Comment: @84104 Yeah, I was chatting to a few users in the SE Meta Tavern about that and I simply went through the process too fast. Bounty can be awarded in two hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You will have to get a list of the IP addresses that those domains use and then add them as exceptions to the firewall.

---

With /etc/hosts.allow you could try something like

```
sshd : localhost : allow
sshd : .wavetelecom.com : allow
sshd : .northhosts.co.uk : allow
sshd : ALL : deny
```

Don't forget to ensure that the hosts in the listed domains have correct reverse dns RRs configured.

Comment: Can't this be done by domain only, and not IP?

Comment: @AlexanderStopher think about this for a moment: How is iptables to know all of the hosts in those domains ?

Comment: Oh and you probably need to know that iptables does hostname->IP resolution once for each hostname when it starts.

Comment: But that's not what I want at all. I want to allow only domains matching the pattern of *.wavetelecom.com and *.northhosts.co.uk, and not all IPs relating to the two domains.

Comment: @AlexanderStopher You can't do that, iptables only resolves names->IP addresses when it starts, to do what you want would require it to do a reverse lookup (at least) every time a new connection is started ...

Comment: Also, your security would be at the mercy of anyone who controls their own rDNS.

Comment: @MadHatter True, but then I don't think it's likely that attackers from China/elsewhere would be able to control their RDNS. I can't do it myself on my home connection, but can at my datacentre.

Comment: There is suspicion in many quarters that much of the cyberactivity from China is indeed government-sponsored; if it were, they would be peculiarly well-able to control their own rDNS.  In any case, that is only one of many reasons why you can't, or shouldn't, do what you want to do.